# How to get child values of an Anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com"> 
        <div id="id11" data-link="yah">
            <div class="s1">
                <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
                <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</a>
<a href="www.google.com"> 
         <div id="id11" data-link="goog"> <div class="s1">
                <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
                <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</a>
```

I want to get the value of data-link when its parent href value =www.yahoo.com or www.google.com
Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click, http://api.jquery.com/data. Also note that those `href` attributes will need to start with a protocol, otherwise they'll be interpreted as relative paths and will lead to 404 errors when clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use pure js using regexp to verify the links..

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(a,function(item){
  if(item.href.match(/www.yahoo.com/) || item.href.match(/www.google.com/)){
  var child=item.children[0];
  console.log(child.getAttribute('data-link'));
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="www.yahoo.com"> 
        <div id="id11" data-link="yah">
            <div class="s1">
                <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
                <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</a>
<a href="www.google.com"> 
         <div id="id11" data-link="goog"> <div class="s1">
                <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
                <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event and access the child's `data` value using [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a").on("click", function() {

      console.log($(this).children().data("link"));

  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="//www.yahoo.com">
  <div id="id11" data-link="yah">
    <div class="s1">
      <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
      <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="//www.google.com">
  <div id="id12" data-link="goog">
    <div class="s1">
      <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
      <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The IDs must be unique. Your hrefs don't start with a protocol, as per roy comment.

If you need to get directly the data link from another function you can write:

```
$('a[href="www.yahoo.com"] > [data-link], a[href="www.google.com"] > [data-link]')
```

Instead, as suggested, you can create a click event handler.

The snippet:

```js
$('a[href="www.yahoo.com"], a[href="www.google.com"]').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).children('div[data-link]').length != 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).children('div[data-link]').data('link'));
    }
})

//
// ..or without events
//
$('a[href="www.yahoo.com"] > [data-link], a[href="www.google.com"] > [data-link]')
   .each((idx, ele) => console.log(ele.dataset.link))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="www.yahoo.com">111
    <div id="id11" data-link="yah">
        <div class="s1">
            <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
            <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="www.google.com">222
    <div id="id12" data-link="goog"> <div class="s1">
        <div class="s2" style="color: white">abc</div>
        <div class="s3" style="color: white">xyx</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a").on("click", function() {

      console.log($(this).children(".subData").attr("data-link"));
  });

})
```

then add a class atrribute to your div:

```
<div id="id12" data-link="goog" class="subData">
```